# Adding items of a 2D list having functions instead of numbers

Tags: python, function, lambda

I'm trying to solve a problem which requires different functions to be put in 2D list. I have the 2D list ready and for the final stage of my work I need to add all the functions in different rows to get to the final function. Once I want to add different items of my list (which are functions).

**I get a type error:**

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'function'.
```

Is there a way to add items of a list with this situation?

Here is a simplified version of my code to duplicate the error:

```
A = [([0] * 2) for row in range(2)]

A[0][0] = lambda x: x
A[0][1] = lambda x: x + 1
A[1][0] = lambda x: x + 2
A[1][1] = lambda x: x + 3

test = A[0][0] + A[0][1]

print(test(1))
```

Comment: What do you expect the "addition" of two functions to be? What you can do is define test as a new lambda, taking x as argument and passing it to the other functions.

Comment: all items are functions, I just want to add all the items in the first row to generate another function which is simply the summation of all the functions in that row...

I tried to pass a new Lambda to the test function but it returns the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Define `test` as a new `lambda`:

```
A = [([0] * 2) for row in range(2)]

A[0][0] = lambda x: x
A[0][1] = lambda x: x + 1
A[1][0] = lambda x: x + 2
A[1][1] = lambda x: x + 3

test = lambda x: A[0][0](x) + A[0][1](x)

print(test(1))
# 3
```

If you have more than two elements in a row, this can be tedious, so use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

test_red = reduce(lambda x, y: lambda z: x(z) + y(z), A[0])
print(test_red(1))
# 3
```

So finally, to generate reduced functions for each row:

```
from functools import reduce

test_all = [reduce(lambda x, y: lambda z: x(z) + y(z), a) for a in A]
print(test_all[0](1))
# 3
print(test_all[1](1))
# 7
```